# Calculate confusion_matrix for Training set with sklearn SVC

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, svm

I want to know the distribution of training data by knowing confusion matrix of it. However, I am not sure if "train_ypre = fir_svm.predict(x_train_1)" is right or wrong.

```
#first stage (asymmetric SVM)
# https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_separating_hyperplane_unbalanced.html : class_weight={0:minority,1:majprity}

fir_svm = SVC(C=10.0,gamma =1,kernel="rbf").fit(x_train_1,y_train_1)
train_fir_score = fir_svm.score(x_train_1,y_train_1)
test_fir_score = fir_svm.score(x_test_1,y_test_1)
print("First SVM score (train) : {0}".format(train_fir_score))
print("First SVM score (test): {0}".format(test_fir_score))
#----------------------------------------------------------
# train (first stage)
train_ypre = fir_svm.predict(x_train_1)
fir_matrix_train = confusion_matrix(y_train_1, train_ypre)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
# train_ypre = fir_svm.predict(x_test_1)
# fir_matrix_train = confusion_matrix(y_test_1, train_ypre)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
print(fir_matrix_train)
TP = fir_matrix_train[0][0]
# print(TP)
FN = fir_matrix_train[0][1]
# print(FN)
FP = fir_matrix_train[1][0]
# print(FP)
TN = fir_matrix_train[1][1]
# print(TN)
precision = TP / (TP+FP) 
print("Precision : {0}".format(precision))
recall = TP / (TP+FN)
print("Recall : {0}".format(recall))
F_measure = 2*recall*precision / (recall+precision)
print("F_measure : {0}".format(F_measure))
auc = roc_auc_score(y_train_1, train_ypre)
print("AUC : {0}".format(auc))
# auc = roc_auc_score(y_test_1, train_ypre)
# print("AUC : {0}".format(auc))
```

[image: Results of code]

Is there any other ways to know more about confusion matrix of training data?

Comment: Could you please write the code instead of including an image? Remember, in order to let people reproduce the error, they should be able to copy-paste your code! :)

Answer (score 0):

A [confusion matrix](https://machinelearningmastery.com/confusion-matrix-machine-learning/) is a table that is often used to describe the performance of a classification model.

The scope of creating a [confusion matrix](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/confusion-matrix-machine-learning/) is to evaluate the performance of our algorithm using *metrics* like `precision`, `recall`, `accuracy` or `F1 score`.

The first mistake I see in your code is that you're using `predict` method on `training set` and this must be used for `test set`.

```
y_pred = fir_svm.predict(x_test_1)
```

Then build `confusion matrix` based on `y_pred` and `y_test_1`.

```
fir_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test_1, y_pred)
```

That's the correct way because you need to see the performance of algorithm based on the `validation` applied for unseen data and not to the `training` data.

Comment: Thanks~~. Is this the right way to examine the confusion matrix of training data? Using trained classifier to predict it's own training data.

Comment: @hanker99, now I see that you're using predict method for train data and that's a mistake.

Comment: @hanker99, I updated my answer with a proper solution for you.

Comment: Yeah, I know it is very weird to do that. However, I am eager to understand the confusion matrix of" training data" to do further researches. Most of my projects are only require confusion matrix of "test". I am tooooooooo newbie so sad haha.

Comment: @hanker99, to answer to your question: a confusion matrix is a table that is often used to describe the performance of a classification model. Using confusion matrix you created we can see the accuracy, precision , recall and F1 score of algorithm.

Comment: That's right. But most of confusion matrix only consider the test data which predicted by trained classifier. The issue is how about training data. There are also misclassified data sample in training data during modeling classifier. Therefore, I want to realize the the accuracy, precision , recall and F1 score of classifier before predict any "test data". In addition, I can tackle some problems such as imbalanced data because some minority data maybe misclassified during training stage of classifier.

Comment: @hanker99, yes, I understood.

Comment: @hanker99, I included some links in order to understand better how confusion matrix works.

Comment: So sad it says confusion matrix must have test or validation data. But confusion matrix only shows the outcome of test or validation data. Is there any other way to realize the situation of training data?

Comment: So sad it says confusion matrix must have test or validation data. But confusion matrix only shows the outcome of test or validation data. Is there any other way to realize the situation of training data?